# Force Webpack 5 in custom storybook addon with v6.5.*

Tags: webpack, storybook, webpack-5, storybook-addon

In Storybook 6.5.0 developers are now able to enable Webpack 5 via the [builder API](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/builders/webpack#webpack-5).

Can I enable Webpack 5 within my custom storybook plugin?

This way all of my components importing my plugin will be forced to use Webpack5.

Comment: What's your exact question? What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @HarshalPatil Can I enable webpack5 via the builder API within a custom storybook plugin? Or is the build API only accessible within the main.js field?